# Working on a simple php/sql user registration script out of boredom. I'm sure there is an easier way. It does function properly

Tags: php, database, post, if-statement, insert

I need to combine all the if statements into one. So, if anyone is a little bore surfing the web I'd appreciate some input =)

I'm currently playing around with some other functions and if anything changes in the mean time I will update.

Thanks!

```
if($_REQUEST['do'] == 'register') {
    $pass_length = strlen($_POST["password1"]);
    $username_length = strlen($_POST["username"]);
    $name_length = strlen($_POST["name"]);
    $email_length = strlen($_POST["email"]);

    if($_POST["verification"] != $_POST["verification_base"]){
        echo "Hey dummy, your verification code does not match!<br>";
        $process = "no";
    }

    if($_POST["password1"] != $_POST["password2"]){
        echo "Your damn passwords do not match!<br>";
        $process = "no";
    }

    if($pass_length <= "3") {
        echo "Your password needs to be more than 3 characters long!<br>";
        $process = "no";
    }

    if($username_length <= "3"){
        echo "Your user name needs to be more than 3 characters long!<br>";
        $process = "no";
    }

    if($name_length <= "2"){
        echo "Please enter a name more than 2 characters long!<br>";
        $process = "no";
    }

    if ($email_length <= "6"){
        echo "Please enter a valid email address!<br>";
        $process = "no";
    }

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password1 = $post["password1"];

    if ($process != "no"){ mysqli_query(
        $con,
        "INSERT INTO $sqlusers (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')"
    );}

}
```

Comment: Why do you feel like you need to combine them into one statement? They perform different comparisons with different criteria - it's fine to have separate `if {}` blocks.

Comment: Sure, there are a couple of ways to refactor this, but I would not worry about the `if` blocks as you have them. It would be different if you had `if ($a == 1) {} else if ($a == 2){} else if ($a == 3) {}` - that would be crying out for refactoring

Comment: What you _do_ need to worry about is the SQL injection vulnerability.  At a minimum, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all those values you're stuffing into the query. Better though , would be to invest your time in learning about prepared statements with a more modern API like MySQLi or PDO.